# Which Well-Known Numbers Are Alexandrian

Tags: number-theory, decimal-expansion

A real number is said to be Decimal Alexandrian if its decimal representation contains every possible finite decimal sequence.
It is a popular question whether $\pi$ is Decimal Alexandrian, or even in other bases. It is suspected to, but a proof has not been found yet. My question is whether any familiar number is. By familiar I mean Something like $0, 5, -8, \pi, e, \sqrt5, \phi, \gamma$, or a billion.

It is easy to generate a number just by picking its expansion, for example the number 0. 00 01 02 10 11 12 20 21 22 100 101 110 111 200 201 210 211 .... is Ternary Alexandrian. But are there any proofs that a well-known real is Alexandrian?

Comment: Every [normal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number) meets this criterion.  This is almost every real number, but almost no familiar number.  For example, rationals are neither normal nor Decimal Alexandrian.

Comment: I'm not familiar with normal numbers. Does every normal number contain every finite sequence, or do they just do so "on average"?

Comment: Where did you see the term "Decimal Alexandrian"? There isn't a well-known standard term for this notion at this time, as far as I know, but "disjunctive in base $10$" has been used in several papers. Related questions: [Irrational Numbers Containing Other Irrational Numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273004/irrational-numbers-containing-other-irrational-numbers) and [Prove there are no hidden messages in Pi](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20566/prove-there-are-no-hidden-messages-in-pi).

Comment: Daron, for a (hopefully) fairly down-to-Earth proof that every normal number contains every finite sequence, see this [23 October 2000 post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=272526) of mine, specifically the paragraph that beings with: *A normal number is one in which each block of digits occurs*

Comment: It came from my head: I thought Alexandrian was a good name because an Alexandrian number contains every book ever written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(Added in response to comment)** According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number), no number that arises naturally from algebra or analysis is *known to be* normal. All known examples are contrived by concatenation of decimal (or other-base) digits.

The [Champernowne constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant) 0.123456789101112131415161718192021222324...., is pretty well known. By construction, it has every finite string of decimal digits not prefixed by zeros. To see that it also has those prefixed by zeros, for example 000000000849102276, just note that such a string is a substring of the same string prefixed by 1: 100000000084912276.

Comment: What I am really interested in is what a proof of normality/Alexandrianity/disjunctivity of a number defined in an algebraic/analytic manner -- without referring to its decimal expansion, say $\sqrt 5$, is -- would even look like,

Comment: @Daron: I added to my answer.